# How to change a picture when a key is entered in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, keyevent

I have a bluetooth keyboard, and when the phone recieves a certain character from that keyboard (eg. 'A') I would like to change a picture on the app.

I'm brand new to Android Studio and I don't understand most of the syntax, so I've been trying to follow tutorials to do this. I've been able to change a picture based on a button click (buttonclick()) as shown in my code, but I don't know how to recieve and handle keys.

As per a tutorial the onKey() function should at least display what was entered in a text field when ENTER is inputted, but so far it does nothing in my app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener {

    private static ImageView imgview; //Image I want to change
    private static Button buttonsbm;  //Button to change image (test)
    private int current_image;        
    int[] images = {R.drawable.circle1, R.drawable.circle2, 
             R.drawable.circle3, R.drawable.circle4, R.drawable.circle5, 
            R.drawable.circle6,
            R.drawable.circle7, R.drawable.circle8};     //Array of images


    EditText text;    //text field

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        text.setOnKeyListener(this);


        //buttonclick();



    }

    //FUNCTION TO CHANGE IMAGE BASED ON BUTTON CLICK
    public void buttonclick() {

        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonsbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonsbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        current_image++;
                        current_image = current_image % images.length;
                        imgview.setImageResource(images[current_image]);
                    }
                }


        );
    }


    //FUNCTION TO CHANGE PICTURE BASED ON KEY INPUTTED (does nothing now)
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int key, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        if (key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            imgview.setImageResource(images[0]);
            Toast.makeText(this, text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return true;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_W) {
            imgview.setImageResource(images[1]);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E) {
            imgview.setImageResource(images[2]);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_R) {
            imgview.setImageResource(images[3]);

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The onKey() function does nothing right now. How do I make it change a picture when the phone recieves a character from my bluetooth keyboard?